# Custom Clone button with ability to validate picklist values for Record Types

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, clone

We have a custom controller for a custom clone button that also checks whether the picklist values are active on a parent record when a Case is being cloned.  If any of the picklist values on the original record are "inactive" that picklist field is cleared on the cloned record and the user is forced to select a new picklist value on the edit screen for that field before the cloned record can be saved.

The problem that we have is that we would also like to prompt the user to select a new picklist value if a picklist value on the original record is no longer visible for that Record Type.  What I mean is that the picklist value has been removed for that particular Record Type but it has not been deleted from the system.  Basically we are trying to prevent the cloned case from having any inactive/deleted picklist values when the case is cloned.

Please let me know if anyone has any ideas how this may be accomplished.  Thank you in advance!

public with sharing class CaseCloneController {

```
static Id parentCaseId {get; set;}
static Case clonedCase {get; set;}

public CaseCloneController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
    parentCaseId = stdController.getRecord().Id; 
}

@RemoteAction
public static PageReference cloneCase() {
    String soql = SelectStarService.createSelectStarSoql('Case');
    soql = soql+' WHERE ID =  :parentCaseId';
    Case parentCase = Database.query(soql);
     clonedCase = parentCase.clone(false, false, false, false);
    validatePicklistValues(); 
    insert clonedCase;
    PageReference pr = new PageReference('/' + clonedCase.Id + '/e?retURL=%2F' + clonedCase.Id);
    return pr;
}

public static void validatePicklistValues() {
    Map<String, Set<String>> fieldMap = getActivePicklistFieldValues();
    for (String field : fieldMap.keySet()) {
        Set<String> valueSet = fieldMap.get(field);
        String value = (String)clonedCase.get(field);
        if (!valueSet.contains(value)) {
            clonedCase.put(field, '');
        }
    }
}

public static Map<String, Set<String>> getActivePicklistFieldValues() {
    Map<String, Set<String>> fieldMap = new Map<String, Set<String>> ();
    Schema.SObjectType objType = Case.getSObjectType(); //this method is used to determine if a list contains sObjects of a particular type
    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult objDescribe = objType.getDescribe();
    Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> sObjectFieldMap = objDescribe.fields.getMap();
    for (Schema.SObjectField field : sObjectFieldMap.values()) {
        if (field.getDescribe().getType().name() == 'Picklist') { 
            Set<String> fieldValues = new Set<String>();
            for (Schema.PicklistEntry value : field.getDescribe().getPicklistValues()) {
                if (value.IsActive()) {
                    fieldValues.add(value.getValue());
                }
            }
            fieldMap.put(field.getDescribe().getName(), fieldValues);
        }
    }
    return fieldMap;
}
```

}

Comment: I haven't tried either of these solutions but these both look promising https://github.com/abhinavguptas/Multi-RecordType-Sobject-Picklist-Describer or http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.com/2012/01/record-type-picklist-values.html

Comment: another option is to use the Apex MetaData API wrapper as provided by Andrew Fawcett - https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi